# Porting visp release to trusty/indigo

Tags: ubuntu-trusty, ubuntu, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm porting visp to indigo. According to http://www.ros.org/debbuild/indigo.html?q=visp it fails for trusty with the followin error (see http://jenkins.ros.org/view/IbinT32/job/ros-indigo-visp_binarydeb_trusty_i386/lastBuild/console):

```
package ros-indigo-visp does not have dependency [ffmpeg]
Dependencies not satisfied for packages: ['ffmpeg']
Process leaked file descriptors. See http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Spawning+processes+from+build for more information
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Build step 'Groovy Postbuild' marked build as failure
Build step 'Groovy Postbuild' marked build as failure
```

In https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/master/rosdep/base.yaml, ffmpeg dependency is now specific for trusty. We have:

```
ffmpeg:
  ubuntu:
     trusty: [libavcodec-dev, libavformat-dev, libavutil-dev, libswscale-dev]
```

I can't understand wy I get this error "Dependencies not satisfied for packages: ['ffmpeg']". It should not happen as ffmpeg is not a dep for trusty. I'm wrong. Is there a problem with the build farm.

Moreover I'm also surprised with the last lines of the log:

```
Build step 'Groovy Postbuild' marked build as failure
```

The build is for indigo. Wy does it mention groovy ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/148471/porting-visp-release-to-trusty/indigo/) by [Fabien Spindler](https://answers.ros.org/users/3990/fabien-spindler/) on ROS Answers with karma: 126 on 2014-04-03

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-04-04**:
cc @William

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2014-04-04**:
@Dirk Thomas @tfoote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to re bloom the package now that the rosdep rules have been updated. The debian metadata is generated by bloom using the rosdep rules. You can just rerun bloom to generate (no upstream release required) new sourcedeb with the updated rosdep mappings.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-04-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0